# How can I arrange multiple classes with abstraction?

Tags: php, oop, pdo, abstract-class

How can I arrange multiple classes with abstraction?

So, there would be one Base abstract class and other three classes would extend Base abstract class.

> The idea is to create an abstract class with all product common logic,
>   like getTitle, setTitle etc. Then create child product classes for
>   each product type to store product type specific logic like furniture
>   sizes, CD size, book weight etc.

Base class - **Main.php**

```
<?php
include "classes/DB.php";

abstract class Main
{
    protected $table;

    private $barcode;
    private $name;
    private $price;
    protected $size;
    protected $height;
    protected $width;
    protected $length;
    protected $weight;
    private $image;

    // SET Parametres
    public function setBarcode($barcode)
    {
        $this->barcode = $barcode;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    abstract function setSize($size);

    abstract function setHeight($height);

    abstract function setWidth($width);

    abstract function setLength($length);

    abstract function setWeight($weight);

    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    // Create Data
    public function insert()
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->table(barcode, name, price, size, height, width, length, weight, image)VALUES(:barcode, :name, :price, :size, :height, :width, :length, :weight, :image)";

        $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':barcode', $this->barcode);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':price', $this->price);
        $stmt->bindParam(':size', $this->size);
        $stmt->bindParam(':height', $this->height);
        $stmt->bindParam(':width', $this->width);
        $stmt->bindParam(':length', $this->length);
        $stmt->bindParam(':weight', $this->weight);
        $stmt->bindParam(':image', $this->image);
        return $stmt->execute();
    }


    // Read Data
    public function readAll()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table";
        $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }

    // Delete Data
    public function delete(array $id)
    {
        $placeholders = trim(str_repeat('?,', count($id)), ',');
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE id IN ($placeholders)";
        $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
        return $stmt->execute($id);
    }
}

?>
```

**Disk.php**

```
<?php
include "classes/Main.php";

class Disk extends Book
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    protected $size;

    // SET Parametre
    public function setSize($size)
    {
        $this->size = $size;
    }
}

?>
```

**Book.php**

```
<?php
include "classes/Main.php";

class Book extends Main
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    protected $weight;

    // SET Parametre
    public function setWeight($weight)
    {
        $this->weight = $weight;
    }
}

?>
```

**Furniture.php**

```
<?php
include "classes/Main.php";

class Furniture extends Disc
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    protected $height;
    protected $width;
    protected $length;

    // SET Parametre
    public function setHeight($height)
    {
        $this->height = $height;
    }

    public function setWidth($width)
    {
        $this->width = $width;
    }

    public function setLength($length)
    {
        $this->length = $length;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

In object-oriented design (OOD), one starts with the specifics then generalises.

In other words---

Step 1: Create the classes that you need for your solution without concerning yourself with inheritance at this stage.

Step 2: Identify and move the common properties ('properties' used in the general sense here) of the classes from step 1 into a base class.

Step 3: Inherit the classes in step 1 from the base class created in step 2.

This approach might be a little difficult because we are trained to design classes the other way round, but it yields better abstractions in my experience.

Comment: @DevelopmentStudio the whole inheritance idea in both your classes and this answer is flawed. You don't extend a disk from a book only because both has a title. this way you would extend a human from a steam boat because both has a name.